# MongoDB natural sort returns data with ObjectIDs shuffled in time

Tags: mongodb, sorting, datetime

I perform the following query:

```
db.preference.find({}, {_id: 1}).sort({$natural: 1}).forEach(function(d) { 
  print(d._id.getTimestamp()) 
})
```

Here's part of the output:

```
Thu Mar 26 2015 12:39:06 GMT+0100 (CEST)
Thu Mar 26 2015 12:41:07 GMT+0100 (CEST)
Thu Mar 26 2015 12:48:55 GMT+0100 (CEST)
Mon Mar 30 2015 17:08:44 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Tue Mar 31 2015 12:34:36 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Tue Mar 31 2015 12:35:01 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Tue Mar 31 2015 12:34:47 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Thu Nov 20 2014 10:55:07 GMT+0100 (CEST)
Wed Apr 29 2015 10:02:33 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Wed Apr 29 2015 10:02:53 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Wed Apr 29 2015 10:03:13 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Wed Apr 29 2015 10:00:11 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Wed Apr 29 2015 10:18:23 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Mon Feb 23 2015 11:54:11 GMT+0100 (CEST)
Tue May 12 2015 16:40:45 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Fri May 15 2015 17:04:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Wed May 14 2014 18:13:40 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Tue Jun 09 2015 14:17:11 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Tue Jun 16 2015 16:03:31 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Tue Nov 04 2014 21:15:21 GMT+0100 (CEST)
Fri Mar 14 2014 10:16:48 GMT+0100 (CEST)
Wed Jun 17 2015 11:14:57 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Fri Mar 14 2014 10:15:30 GMT+0100 (CEST)
```

It's easy to see that the dates are seriously shuffled, while I expected strictly ascending order.

Collection is not capped, and the documents are often modified. ObjectIds are never generated in the code explicitly. Collection is not shared.

Any ideas why natural sorting works this way?

Can someone explain while natural ordering works in.

Comment: `$natural` returns the order on disk, so documents can be moved around. Either explicitly `.sort({ "_id": 1 })` which will then "sort" in timestamp order or create a timestamp. Even without `$natural` the order will not always be ascending in order of timestamp.

Comment: Documents can move on disk if an update operation can't fit the document  current space, i.e. the document grows. This may explain the shuffle

Answer (score 2):

What did you expect?

> Use the $natural operator to use natural order for the results of a
>   sort operation. Natural order refers to the logical ordering of
>   documents internally within the database.
>
> The $natural operator uses the following syntax to **return documents in
>   the order they exist on disk**: ...

See [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/).